# Mocking UUID in Python dataclasses

Tags: python, mocking, python-dataclasses

I have dataclasses with uuids like this:

```
import uuid

from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Union

@dataclass
class Foo:
    id: Union[uuid.UUID, None] = field(default_factory=uuid.uuid4)
```

When I call `Foo()` it creates an object with a generated UUID - fine.

Now I want to mock this UUID factory in a test, like this:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

TEST_UUIDS = ["uuid1", "uuid2"]

with patch.object(uuid, "uuid4", side_effects=TEST_UUIDS):
    print(uuid.uuid4())  # Output: uuid1
    print(Foo().id)  # Output: an actual UUID
```

My expected output is `uuid2`. So the question: How do I have to patch the factory correctly? Couldn't find anything in the docs or here...

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** It is probably best to just do `print(Foo(id="uuid1").id)`

### Explanation

Here is what does not work: (apart from the typo at side_effect(s))

```
with patch.object(uuid, "uuid4", side_effect=TEST_UUIDS):
    print(id(uuid.uuid4))
    print(id(Foo.__dataclass_fields__["id"].default_factory))
```

Outputs:

```
140470453723216
140470456506848
```

This is because **patch is not changing the actual `uuid.uuid4` function, but creating a new one**, overwriting the normal `uuid.uuid4` in the namespace, as seen by the change in id. Since the factory is already initialized, this change has no effect, unless you create the class inside the `with` block, which is impractical for a real life test.

But even if it did, that would not make a difference, because [dataclass](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/) *generates* the `__init__` function, and creates the reference to the default factory exactly once at [during the class definition](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/dataclasses.py#L415-L420), and not for every single `__init__` call. Therefore, the following also *does not work*:

```
with patch.object(Foo.__dataclass_fields__["id"], "default_factory",
                  side_effect=TEST_UUIDS):
    print(Foo().id)
```

What you can do is overriding the `__init__` function:

```
from copy import copy
#  Copy is required to avoid recursion after rewrite
foo_init_copy = copy(Foo.__init__)
def mock_init(foo):
    foo_init_copy(foo)
    foo.id = "x"

with patch.object(Foo, "__init__", new=mock_init):
   ...
```

Which seems a like a little overkill to me, if the factory normally does not implement complicated logic. If that is the case, one can also consider creating a normal class instead of a data class.